# Не получается передать данные из формы через curl

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Пытался всяко разно сделать передачу данных из формы на сайт (api) через curl, но видимо что-то не так понимаю в этой библиотеке, хоть примеров и много в интернете. Можете подсказать, как передать их? Заранее благодарю <3

Код с формой:

```
        <h2 class="popup-title">Справка о периоде обучения</h2>
        <form class="reference-form" action="">
            <div class="reference-select">
                <select class="groups" name="groups" id="groups">
                    <option value="default" disabled selected>Выберите группу</option>
                    <?php
                    $groups = loadGroups();
                    foreach($groups as $group){
                    ?>
                    <option id="<?=$group['id']?>" value="<?=$group['id']?>"><?=$group['name']?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="reference-select">
                <select class="obiturients" name="obiturients" id="obiturients">
                    <option value="default" disabled selected>ФИО</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="reference-btn">Создать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Код ajax

```
    $('.reference-link').magnificPopup();
    $('.groups').change(function () {
    let gid = $(this).val();
    let form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {gid: gid}
    }).done(function (obiturient) {
        console.log(obiturient);
        obiturient = JSON.parse(obiturient);
        form.find('[name="obiturients"]').empty();
        obiturient.forEach(function (obiturient) {
            form.find('[name="obiturients"]').append('<option value='+ obiturient.id +'>' + obiturient.O_fam + ' ' +  obiturient.O_name + ' ' + obiturient.O_otch + '</option>')
        })
    })

})

})
```

data.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
if (isset($_POST['gid'])) {
    global $obiturient;
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'rups');
    $stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `obiturient` WHERE `group_id`= " . $_POST['gid']);
    $obiturient = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($obiturient);
}
function loadGroups(){
    global $groups;
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'rups');
    $stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `groups`");
    $groups = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $groups;
}
```

Нужно передать именно

```
append('<option value='+ obiturient.id +'>
```

Сам cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init(); //инициализация сеанса
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://diplom/example.php'); //урл сайта к которому обращаемся
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //выводим заголовки
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //передача данных методом POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //теперь curl вернет нам ответ, а не выведет
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, //тут переменные которые будут переданы методом POST
array (
'obiturients'=>$_POST['obiturients'],
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MSIE 5'); //эта строчка как-бы говорит: "я не скрипт, я IE5" :)
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://ya.ru"); //а вдруг там проверяют наличие рефера
$res = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

из второго бокса формы , но у меня не получилось вытащить value по примерам из интернета и отправить это значение. Еще раз благодарю заранее за Вашу помощь.

Comment: чет не вижу php кода

Comment: вообще не вижу здесь никакого CURL, сложно сказать, вроде все нормально, если нет ошибок вариантов несколько: 1) select ничего не возвращает 2) может в таблице бд нет такого значения, которое приходит $_POST['gid']

Comment: Прикрепил cURL , надеюсь поможет найти проблему

Comment: мы не сможем так помочь, тут скорее всего где-то в переменную приходит пустота, у тебя нигде нет проверки на корректность данных, существет ли $_POST['...'], возвращает ли что-либо запрос к БД, возвращает ли что-то curl и так далее.... отладчик включи и сразу все станет понятно.

Comment: Вот скрин того, что отправилось вроде бы норм, но оно отправляет данные из двух боксов формы, а нам нужно только значение "value" в option , которое мы прописали в аяксе, будем признательны, если Вы помогли бы достать это значение :3.
Скриншот: https://yapx.ru/v/MSqgS

Comment: Ну и также, я не понимаю, работает ли у нас cURL вообще, или нет (ибо впервые с этой библиотекой работаю), либо же просто пост из формы отправляет сам.